# Langchain - rely ONLY on the context

Tags: chatbot, llama-index, py-langchain

My goal is to make a ChatBot able to:

1. have memory
2. take as input some documents
3. rely ONLY on the documents given and say "I don't know" when the information is not in the input documents.

I found this tutorial, super useful: https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/blob/main/examples/chatbot/Chatbot_SEC.ipynb

It works perfectly, BUT I don't understand how to apply point 3 (rely only on input documents).

Do you think that with LangChain is easier? Thanks a lot and have a nice day! Carlo

Noticing that

```
create_llama_chat_agent
```

relies on langchain/agents/conversational/prompt.py file to build the prompt, I manipulated that PREFIX text to say something like "please rely only on your context" but it is not effective.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tests, it was easier than expected.
Using this: https://blog.langchain.dev/tutorial-chatgpt-over-your-data/

I simply modified the QA_PROMPT saying to answer questions only when related to the context.

It is working !

Hope this is useful for you guys, have a nice day! Carlo

Comment: can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to write a code (using local `sentence-transformers` VectorStore and `GPT4All`'s `Mistral` LLM, all locally installed) that should achieve what you want, for your reference.

```py
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")


from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.memory import VectorStoreRetrieverMemory
vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(
    ["Harry Potter's owl is in the castle"], embedding=embeddings)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs=dict(k=1))
memory = VectorStoreRetrieverMemory(retriever=retriever)


from langchain_community.llms import GPT4All
llm = GPT4All(
    model="/home/jeff/.cache/huggingface/hub/gpt4all/mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf",
    device='gpu',
    n_threads=8)

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = """You're a helpful assistant, aiming at solving the problem.

Relevant pieces of previous conversation:
{history}

(You do not need to use these pieces of information if not relevant)

Answer my question: {input}
"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
   input_variables=["history", "input"], template=_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE
)


from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
conversation_with_summary = ConversationChain(
   llm=llm,
   prompt=PROMPT,
   memory=memory,
   verbose=True
)
# result = conversation_with_summary.predict(input="Where is the hedwig? Why is it in castle?")

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter your question: ")
    if user_input == "exit":
        break
    else:
        result = conversation_with_summary.predict(input=user_input)
        print(result)
```